# How to order lexicographically the monomers of a parametrized polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

I want to order lexicographically the monomials in a "parametrized polynomial", i.e. polynomials whose "symbolic bits" may be either "variables" or "parameters".  For example:

```
In[1]:= Expand[(x + a y + a^2 z)^3] /. a^n_ -> a^Mod[n, 3]

Out[1]= x^3 + y^3 + 6 x y z + z^3 + 3 x^2 y a + 3 y^2 z a + 3 x z^2 a +  3 x y^2 a^2 +
 3 x^2 z a^2 + 3 y z^2 a^2
```

In the polynomial above `x`, `y`, and `z` are intended as "variables", whereas `a` is intended as a "parameter".

The documentation for *Mathematica* states that monomials in a polynomial are ordered lexicographically by default, but if so, I don't understand why the two terms with `x^2` come after the `y^3` term in the polynomial above, for example.

So my question is: how can I force a lexicographic ordering of the monomials with respect to the "variables" (i.e. `x`, `y`, and `z`).  (In particular, for the polynomial above, the symbol `a` should be disregarded for the ordering.)

For example, the desired ordering for the polynomial above would be

```
x^3 + 3 x^2 y a + 3 x^2 z a^2 + 3 x y^2 a^2 + 3 x z^2 a + 6 x y z + y^3 + 3 y^2 z a + 3 y z^2 a^2 + z^3
```

Comment: something like: `TraditionalForm[Expand[(x+a y+a^2 z)^3]/.a^n_->a^Mod[n,3], ParameterVariables->{a}]` ?

Comment: @chuy: thanks!  (I was thrown off by the fact that the docs describe `ParameterVariables` as "an option for `GroebnerBasis` and `PolynomialReduce`.")  If you care to post your comment as an answer, I'll be glad to accept it as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you can use something like:

```
TraditionalForm[Expand[(x+a y+a^2 z)^3]/.a^n_->a^Mod[n,3], ParameterVariables:>{a}]
```

This information can be found in the following: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PolynomialOrderings.html (toward the bottom)

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately, since my last comment I discovered some serious problems with this approach.  I describe them in an EDIT to my post.

Comment: I suppose I don't understand your question well enough then.  I thought this was primarily for display purposes.  What is wrong with using `MonomialList[expr, {x, y, z}, "Lexicographic"]` where `exp` is the polynomial?

Comment: OK, now I see what's going on: the output of the original expression I posted does not reflect the internal ordering.